# Loading .bin pretrain fasttext models from Azure Blob Storage into Azure Synapse Notebook

Tags: python, azure-blob-storage, azure-synapse, fasttext

Does anyone know how to load pretrained .bin fasttext model into azure synapse notebook using fasttext.load_model function? My .bin file is on azure blob storage account

I try to load using the function

fasttext.load_model(aure_blob_storage_path_file)
but I get error like
.dfs.core.windows.net/cc.sr.300.bin cannot be opened for loading!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get model in storage by mounting the storage account in azure synapse.
Follow below steps.

```
mssparkutils.fs.mount(
    "wasbs://<container>@<storage_account_name>.blob.core.windows.net",
    "/mnt/",
    {"accountKey":"<your_storage_account_key>"})
```

Then after mounting you list down the file by giving path as below format.
`/synfs/{jobId}/mnt/{filename}`

[image]

Here, in my case job id is 0 and `/mnt/` is mount point, find out what is yours job id and list down files giving mount point.

Next, by giving this path load the model.

```
import fasttext

azure_blob_storage_path_file = "/synfs/0/mnt/model_1.bin"
model = fasttext.load_model(azure_blob_storage_path_file)
model.predict("Give the github links.")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

While I'm unfamiliar with the specific limitations of these Azure services, it's likely that the `load_model()` routine is trying to do some random-access on the file that may not be supported for those simulated filesystem volumes.

You will likely need to pre-download the file from cloud storage into a local volume path, which offers traditional full random-access reading of file ranges, for that `load_model()` operation to succeed.